# Kraken API AddOrder passes successfully but order is not placed on Kraken

Tags: api, cryptocurrency

I'm trying Kraken APIs via C# and I managed to call public APIs as well as private APIs for getting the balance and getting open orders. But when I wanted to try an AddOrder API I encountered a problem, the API is executed successfully, but there is no order on Kraken.

Below is the result I get after calling AddOrder API. It seems normal, no errors and all parameters are as I specified them (sell 0.01 btc at 8100.00 usd)

```
{"error":[],"result":{"descr":{"order":"sell 0.01000000 XBTUSD @ limit 8100.0"}}}
```

But there is no order on Kraken platform. Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that **parameter validate has to be false**!!
 
By default I set validate to true (which should be desired I guess),
but it does not work.
With validate == false order is placed correctly.
FYI, even if validate == false, basic input arguments check is performed.

Answer (score 2):

As @Milos found, `validate = False` will place the order.

From the documentation https://www.kraken.com/features/api#add-standard-order

> validate = validate inputs only.  do not submit order (optional)

Answer (score 0):

When adding an order setting validate=true is a good means of testing. If you want to execute the order, set validate=false.